# Поиск в массиве объектов на яндекс карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, карты

На странице выводится карта

```
points // Массив объектов type: "Feature" 
window.myObjects = ymaps
  .geoQuery({
  type: "FeatureCollection",
   features: points
  })
  .addToMap(myMap);
  myMap = myMap;
```

После этого нужно выполнить фильтрацию объектов по id Не могу понять можно ли выполнить фильтрацию по массиву с id

```
this.filter = ['1', '5', '7'] // массив id
let filter_c = new ymaps.GeoQueryResult(),
 shownObjects;
  filter.forEach(ele => {
   filter_c = myObjects.search(`options.id = ${ele}`);
   shownObjects = filter_c.addToMap(myMap);
 });
myObjects.remove(shownObjects).removeFromMap(.myMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let filter = new ymaps.GeoQueryResult();
newVal.forEach((ele, i) => {
   filter = myObjects.search(`options.id = ${ele}`).add(filter);
});
const shownObjects = filter.addToMap(this.myMap);
 myObjects.remove(shownObjects).removeFromMap(this.myMap);
```